# Bruno Latour on the globe

Tags: metaphysics

How do you understand what Bruno Latour means when he says, "The globe is not actually something which has any existence."
at 46:59 https://t.co/CVgYmUHxsi

and, "the destruction of the image of the globe"
https://youtu.be/4-l6FQN4P1c

and, "the Earth itself might not be a globe after all"
http://www.bruno-latour.fr/node/700

Comment: See [his interview](https://www.academia.edu/29003627/_There_is_no_Earth_corresponding_to_the_Globe_-_An_Interview_with_Bruno_Latour_), "globe" and "Earth" have very technical meanings:"*My Gaia – which is, of course, Lovelock's Gaia – indicates a non-global, a non-total vision... Whereas the Moderns had the globe
as a horizon in the Husserlian sense, now we are suddenly re-territorializing and re-grounding... When we were
modernizing, we departed from the land in the direction of the globe. But now the globe has disappeared, we fully understand that the globe has been a fiction.*"

Answer (score 1):

Latour is adopting a provocatively paradoxical way of talking; he is using language to seize our attention. He is not a supporter of the Flat Earth Society. Essentially he is making a point (which one can assess for oneself) about globalisation :

> For all that to function as a frame of reference, the elites themselves also had
>   to believe in the existence of a world, of a globe, that had the potential to become a
>   universally modernised planet, if only they were able to bring it about.
>   It’s at this point that we have to combine commonplace analysis of the
>   political sphere with that of another sphere entirely: the planet that has made its
>   entrance into politics. The historic importance of COP21 was that it enabled us to
>   become cognisant of an entirely different way of proceeding: **this planet Earth
>   does not in any way resemble the globe of globalisation. To put it bluntly: there is
>   no planet corresponding to the Promised Land of globalisation.** There has been a
>   signalling error! And so those positions no longer need to take their bearings
>   solely by means of the classical polarisation that ranges from local to global, from
>   national to universal, from identity to the ‘wide open spaces’ of the global market. (http://www.bruno-latour.fr/sites/default/files/downloads/2016-01-3-TERRITORIES-GB.pdf - emphasis mine.)

I think it's this perspective on his remarks to which Conifold pointed in his Comment.

Answer (score -1):

There is an entire chapter devoted to Bruno Latour in

> Fashionable Nonsense: Postmodern Intellectuals' Abuse of Science
>   Authors   Alan Sokal, Jean Bricmont Publisher St Martins Press (ny), 1999

The same book was also published as:

> Intellectual Impostures Authors   Jean Bricmont, Alan Sokal
>   Publisher Profile Books, 2011

The titles themselves are suggestive enough of how Latour may be understood in general, but here is a quote from a review on Google Books.

> In 1996, Alan Sokal published an essay in the hip intellectual
>   magazine Social Text parodying the scientific but impenetrable lingo
>   of contemporary theorists. Here, Sokal teams up with Jean Bricmont to
>   expose the abuse of scientific concepts in the writings of today's
>   most fashionable postmodern thinkers. From Jacques Lacan and Julia
>   Kristeva to Luce Irigaray and Jean Baudrillard, the authors document
>   the errors made by some postmodernists using science to bolster their
>   arguments and theories. Witty and closely reasoned, Fashionable
>   Nonsense dispels the notion that scientific theories are mere
>   "narratives" or social constructions, and explored the abilities and
>   the limits of science to describe the conditions of existence.

Comment: I find the expression "mere social construct" upsettingly funny, or funnily upseting. There is nothing "mere" in a social construct; a social construct isn't ontologically less real than a table or a rock.